# I want to post array param in HttpURLConnection android

Tags: java, android, web-services, arraylist, httpurlconnection

I am a fresher in developing Android apps, in my app I want to post params in the format below:

```
user_id=12&task_id=100&user_ids=["91","92"]
```

I am not able to send the `user_ids` in array format. I am receiving the `user_ids` as string in my Rails API.

I am using HttpURLConnection, and in my `writer.write()` I am passing my post params as

```
writer.write("user_id="+id+"&task_id="+tid+"&user_ids="+["91","92"]+");
```

Please help.

Comment: you haven't pass any array, you make a string like array that's why you got string on rails side, why don't you use volley for calling web services, as you can send JSONArray with your request

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sending user_ids in array format? Do you actually have a String array holding those values? If so, maybe you're looking for `writer.write("user_id="+id+"&task_id="+tid+"&user_ids="+Arrays.deepToString(uid));`

Comment: Basically i have a list of user_ids and i want those ids to post to my server to get the desired result

Comment: @Calvin P i tried using Arrays.deepToString but even that doesnt seem to work

Comment: I have a JSONArray of format ["91", "92"], and i want this array to post as it is with a identifier name as user_ids=["91","92"] along with two more params, i.e, user_id and task_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any one facing the same problem, I found a work around.
You need to add the array in a string

**1. Step 1**

```
Create a final ArrayList<String> SelectedTagIds = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add the array items using

```
SelectedTagIds.add("One");
SelectedTagIds.add("Two");
...
```

**2. Step 2**

Convert

```
SelectedTagIds.toString();
```

**3. Step 3**

Format the String by replacing the string to

```
SelectedTagIds.replace("[","").replace("]","").replaceAll("\\s","").trim();
```

**4 Step 4**

Finally post the String to the server (I used HttpURLConnection to post my data to the server), and in the server code, convert the received SelectedTagIds to Array and loop accordingly to achieve you'r desired result.